# Programattically set barbutton " System Item"

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonsystemitem

I want to set share button on rightbarbuttonitem of navigation controller.
I don't want to add custom images , I want use share button image provided by Xcode.This is how I do in storyboard. 
I set **Style** , and set **System_Item** as ***Action***.

[image]

[image]

Now the question is how do I set **System_Item** programatically, if I create barbuttonitem programatically ?

```
let shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "",
                                  style: .plain,
                                  target: self,
                                  action: #selector(shareAction(sender:)))
    shareButton.tintColor = AppColor.barButtonColor

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use UIBarButtonSystemItemAction option to get share action directly

```
   let share = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareAction(sender:)))
    shareButton.tintColor = AppColor.barButtonColor
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = share
```

and handle the action as like

```
@objc func shareAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension to do this ->

```swift
public extension UIViewController {

    func setRightBarButtonItem(tintColor: UIColor = AppColor.barButtonColor) {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)

        button.tintColor = tintColor
        button.setImage(UIImage(.action), for: .normal) // <-- Set system icon to button

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    }

    @objc func tap() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Then in your ViewController

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setRightBarButtonItem()

    // OR

    setRightBarButtonItem(tintColor: .blue)
}
```

---

UIImage extension to use system icons without version control

```swift
extension UIImage {

  public convenience init?(_ systemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem) {

    guard let sysImage = UIImage.imageFrom(systemItem: systemItem)?.cgImage else {
      return nil
    }

    self.init(cgImage: sysImage)
  }

  private class func imageFrom(systemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem) -> UIImage? {

    let sysBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: systemItem, target: nil, action: nil)

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.setItems([sysBarButtonItem], animated: false)
    toolBar.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)

    if let buttonView = sysBarButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView{
      for subView in buttonView.subviews where subView is UIButton {
        let button = subView as! UIButton
        let image = button.imageView!.image!
        return image
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```